# SpamAssassin Solutions

Tags: spam-prevention, email-spam, spamassassin

Hi I am sending some campaigns through ElasticEmails and these are the SpamAssassin rules scores of my campaigns.

- 0.2 JAM_LONG_LINK : BODY: Very long link in mail, possibly filled up with
- 0.8 HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST : BODY: HTML font color similar to background
- 0.6 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_04 : BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image area
- 0.5 JAM_LARGE_FONT_SIZE : RAW: Body of mail contains parts with very large

How can I avoid these filters?

Long links are added by ElasticEmails. I have no control over this.
What font size is large as per SpamAssassin rule?
I am using black font through out the email. I have few section with dark colors and the fonts on these sections are white. Everything is clearly visible. I have tested by changing the whole template background to a slightly darker color, but the filter still catches it.

Because of these issues my email delivery is seriously affected. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- JAM_LARGE_FONT_SIZE

After several trial and error I found that anything above 30 was considered too large. A small portion of my email had size 34. It was a header. I reduced its font size to 26px and gave it a bold style. Now that issue is solved.

- HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST

This was trickier. So I explored the SpamAssassin rules and found out that all the text element should have a background-color and color attribute. It doesn't matter if the parent elements have these attributes. In my case, the parent element had background-color attribute so everything looked fine. But for SpamAssassin that was not enough. If background-color attribute is not present on a Text element, SpamAssassin will use the default value (#ffffff).

Adding a background-color attribute on all the Text elements rectified this problem.